# using R's `igraph` and `ggraph` to plot a graph with 8 milion edges nodes and 32 milion edges in a stress layout

Tags: r, igraph, ggraph, rcpparmadillo

I need to visualize a graph in `R` using ggraph. Smaller graphs (~30k edges) gave me reasonable plots with this code

```
library(ggraph)
layout_stress <- graphlayouts::layout_with_sparse_stress(fullg_siblings_focus, pivots = 250)
ggg <- ggraph(graph, layout=layout_stress) +
    geom_edge_arc(aes(color=link))
```

Now that my graph has 7 m nodes, I get this error when I call `layout_with_sparse_stress()`

```
Error in sparseStress(y, D, RpL, pivs, A, iter) : 
  SpMat::init(): requested size is too large; suggest to enable ARMA_64BIT_WORD
```

So it seems no ggraph/igraph layout is suitable for such a large graph. Or is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Do you have enough memory? Have you googled: "enable ARMA_64BIT_WORD"? Is it possible to enable a 64 bit word?

Comment: There are not 8 million pixels in a HD screen. What plot do you expect to see?